# Converting asp.net website to mobile site

Tags: asp.net, mobile

I have my Desktop version ready.Is there is any faster method or tool which will help me to convert my website to mobile site.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [link](https://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application). This may help you.

The best way is to add a separate mobile site and have mobile browsers redirect to this.

Go through this [guide](http://buildinternet.com/2011/01/add-a-mobile-landing-page-to-your-site/) for adding a separate mobile site .